# How to use custom font (any external font) as embedded resource in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use custom external font **(Monotype Corsiva)** as Embedded resource in my Xamarin Forms project. I am using Xamarin.Forms version 4.5.0.617

> I have added **"MonotypeCorsiva.ttf"** font file in my project and set **Build action: Embedded resource** in Solution Explorer.
>
> I have added `[assembly: ExportFont("MonotypeCorsiva.ttf", Alias = "MyFont")]` in **App.xaml.cs**
>
> I am using it inside a `Label` in my **XAML** page:
>
> ```xml
> <Label Text="Hello" FontFamily="MonotypeCorsiva" FontSize="Medium" />
> ```

Am I doing everything correct, am I missing anything?

I am getting error :

**In UWP Build:** in **MyApplication.UWP\App.xaml.cs**
[image]

**In Android Build**

I got similar error in **MyApplication.Droid\MainActivity.cs**

`System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 01000072 from typeref (expected class 'Xamarin.Forms.ExportFontAttribute' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')'`

Comment: I havn't used the latest decorator attribut included in Xamarin Forms 4.5 as a preview feature. It might not be very stable yet and not available to all platform yet too. Try on Android/iOS first. I see you also use an alias, don't you neet to use it on the fontfamily instead of the name ? I'm using the old way to include fonts by adding them to each platform so I can't provide more help sorry.

Comment: @Nk54, I ahve also tried on Android, but I got similar error `System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 01000072 from typeref (expected class 'Xamarin.Forms.ExportFontAttribute' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')'`

Comment: Try updating the package in every platform ? Try without the alias (btw you didn't answer : did you try to set it like that <Label Text="a" FontFamily="MyCustomFont"  /> ? Are you using the chanel for testing ? I've red somewhere that someone made it work on Android. My thought is either it's not the right package (pre), or your alias, or your font file properties. I cannot help more sorry. Keep me update when you got it working !

Comment: JIC, there's a UWP bug for custom fonts registered inXF repo: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10307

Comment: Why dont you put the ttf in your android asset folder and set the build type is AndroidAsset.?

Comment: Because Xamarin gave us a new way to avoid putting every fonts in each platform you target which can be boring compared to the new way provided in 4.5 : see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.5/4.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, just updated the NuGet package **Xamarin.Forms** to version 4.5.0.617 in all projects in my Solution.

Previously I had updated Xamarin.Forms NuGet Package to version 4.5x only in  the shared project. Hence this error was encountered

> ```cs
> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type Xamarin.Forms.ExportFontAttribute'`
> ```

Now I have Updated Xamarin.Forms NuGet in all projects (Android, iOS and UWP) in my solution to version 4.5x. Please note that using external custom fonts as Embedded resource in Xamarin Forms requires Xamarin.Forms version 4.5x or later [refer to this link for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#Using_a_Custom_Font)

Now the proper way to do it:

- Suppose I want to use ***Monotype Corsiva*** font in my project and use it as embedded resource.
- **Update Xamarin.Forms to version 4.5.0.530 or later in all projects** in solution (Android, iOS, UWP, etc.). To do it, In **Solution Explorer**, **Right Click** Solution name -> **Manage NuGet Packages for solution** -> **Update Xamarin.Forms package to 4.5x or later** -> **Select all projects** and update.
- Add a font file (.ttf) in your shared project.
- Set the file as **Embedded resource** (**Right Click** Font file in **Solution Explorer** -> **Properties** -> **Build Action:** Set as **Embedded resource**).
- Add `[assembly: ExportFont("FontFileName.ttf", Alias = "MyFont")]` before any namespace of any class in your project. No need to add full path of the font file. It would be better if you add new class and add the above mentioned code before starting namespace. Just like:

```cs
[assembly: ExportFont("MonotypeCorsiva.ttf", Alias = "MyFont")]
namespace MyApplication.Extensions
{    
    public class ExportFont
    {
        // You can have an empty class
        ... 
    }
}
```

- Now use it in any XAML page just like

```xml
<Label Text="Hello" FontFamily="MonotypeCorsiva" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

- You can use Alias name or Font Name in XAML code. `FontFamily = "MyFont"` is also correct.
- Now Run the project.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore 2023

Answer (score -1):

try as following

```
<Label TextColor="#934293" Text="Swanky" FontSize="80">
    <Label.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="iOS">Cabin Sketch</On>
            <On Platform="Android">CabinSketch-Reg.ttf#Cabin Sketch</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>
```

Comment: Actually, he IS using the latest way to use font. Take a look to Xamarin Forms 4.5 pre release note. With latest way to use font you don't need all the boilerplate and to include fonts in every platform.
Proof here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.5/4.5.0