# How to use Font Awesome icons in project as an icon of ImageButton

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I am having a problem to realize how to use Font Awesome icons in my Xamarin application, I want to use it with `ImageButton`as icon. And most tutorials I found didn't help me understand how it works.

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: How to implement and use font awesome icons

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As explained in [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#set-the-font-family):

1. You need to first to have the font file I believe `.ttf` (or .otf).
2. Add it to your shared project.
3. Right click on the file and click on "properties", then set it build action to **Embedded Resource**.
4. Export it with a friendly alias name in your `AssemblyInfo.cs` or `App.xaml.cs`:

`[assembly: ExportFont("file-name.ttf", Alias = "FontAwesome")]`

5. Consume it:

```
<Label FontFamily="FontAwesome" Text="&#xf004;"/>
```

For the list of icons code take a look at [FontAwesome codes](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/).

---

If you want to use it with click capabilities like a button, then you can use a label with [GestureRecognizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap):

```
<Label FontFamily="FontAwesome" Text="&#xf004;">
     <Label.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
     </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

---

## UPDATE

Even better use an `ImageButton` with a `FontImageSource` property instead of a label, you have click capabilities of a button also I found interesting that you can change the color of your glyph icon, weather hard-coded or dynamically depending on the [selected theme](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/app-themes-xamarin-forms/), here is an example:

```
<ImageButton>
    <ImageButton.Source>
        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesome"
                         Glyph="{x:Static fonts:IconFont.AddressBook}"
                         Color="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White,
                                                 Light=Black}"/>
    </ImageButton.Source>
</ImageButton>
```

You can also define a static class having `const string` properties, each one having as value the code corresponding to an icon glyph and as name a description of it that way you will need to provide only the description instead of the code like I did with `Glyph="{x:Static fonts:IconFont.AddressBook}"`, it will looks something like this:

```
 static class IconFont
    {
        public const string Ad = "\uf641";
        public const string AddressBook = "\uf2b9";
...
}
```

I invite you to follow this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-oFC2lOQwI) and check out [this GitHub Page](https://andreinitescu.github.io/IconFont2Code/) which generate the static c# class for you starting from a font glyph file that you submit.

Comment: What if i want to use it as icon in ImageButton?

Comment: any other way to use it, like in label or etec. to look like button (clickable)

Comment: yes, check my update with GestureRecognizers

Comment: Good to know :)

Comment: Thx this was extremely helpful

Comment: Don't forget to add a reference to the IconFont class's namespace in the header of the page's XAML file. 
Something like this:

`xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE"`

Then I had to write out the Glyph attribute like so:
`Glyph="{x:Static Member=constants:Constants.AddressBook}"`

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome have multiple framework supported (Vue, React, Angular, WordPress, LESS, SCSS). But I don't know why they are not providing it for Xamarin Forms and MAUI.

I have created custom control for Xamarin Forms and MAUI.

Instructions are available at
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Brushtail.FontAwesome.Mobile/

Feedbacks are welcome.