# Using Material Design Icons with Xamarin Forms - What Am I Missing?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, app.xaml

I am trying to modify the default Xamarin Forms (Flyout) App template to use Material Design Icons for the `FlyoutItem` icons, instead of the supplied `.png` files.  I have tried to follow [this blog post by James Montemagno](https://montemagno.com/using-font-icons-in-xamarin-forms-goodbye-images-hello-fonts/), and tried to use his [Hanselman.Forms](https://github.com/ScottSEA/Hanselman.Forms) project as a reference... but I'm missing something.

**Note:** *At this point, I don't have access to an iPhone or a Mac, so I'm just concentrating on the Android project.*

I have done the following steps:

1. Imported the `materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf` file into the Assets folder and double-checked that its `Build Action` is set to `AndroidAsset`.
2. Added the following to the `App.xaml` file:

```xml
<OnPlatform x:Key="MaterialFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
   <On Platform="Android" Value="materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf#Material Design Icons" />
</OnPlatform>

<x:String x:Key="IconAbout">&#xf2fd;</x:String>
```

3. Modified the AppShell.xaml to change the icon:

```xml
<FlyoutItem Title="About">
   <FlyoutItem.Icon>
      <FontImageSource Glyph="{StaticResource IconAbout}"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}" 
                       Color="Black"/>
   </FlyoutItem.Icon>
   <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

This is a direct copy from the `Hanselman.Forms` project's `TabItem` - I thought the FontFamily would have to be a `DynamicResource`, but apparently not, because it works *as is* in that project, but doesn't work in mine either way - the icon is always blank (actually, if I change the `Glyph` to a letter `A` I get an "A" for an icon, but that's not really helpful).

I'm missing some dumb little detail that I just can't see.

Comment: That James' blog is an old version, check this [Embedded Fonts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/), easy to implement.

Comment: And put a label to test your font setup.

Comment: As I said to @Tommy99 below - that is an excellent alternative but my goal is to understand what I'm overlooking - there is a gap in my understanding that is not filled by a different implementation.  Once I get this working, I'll definitely refactor to this approach!

Comment: Alright. Let's start with ```<Label Text="&#xf2fd;" FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}">``` then, is the label appears OK?

Comment: @Shaw - nope; it doesn't.  Trying to implement your alternative led me to a bad glyph code (see my posted answer).  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Font Awesome icons in project as an icon of ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095134/how-to-use-font-awesome-icons-in-project-as-an-icon-of-imagebutton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the error is here:

```
<x:String x:Key="IconAbout">&#xf2fd;</x:String>
```

Changing that character code to `&#xf02df;` got everything working - one missing zero and the result is chaos.  Many thanks to @shaw and @tommy99 - trying to implement their answer (and it still not working) led me to the solution.  I've upvoted their solution/comments in thanks.

Comment: All good, the main difference for me from my link is that it requires one copy of font files into the shared project rather than put them everywhere. Other steps are just quite similar since you've got it working.

Comment: A better way to avoid confusion is to define the glyph codes in a static class as string properties and deal with their explicit descriptif name instead of their value (code). https://stackoverflow.com/a/65095438/5228202

Answer (score 8):

I've gotten it to work.

First of all, go to this GitHub repo and download this material font family as a .tff file. Click on the 'font' file in the repo and download `MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf`.

Link: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

[image]

[image]

[image]
Place the .tff file in your shared project.

[image]

Now reference the font in the **assemblyinfo.cs** file like so:

```
[assembly: ExportFont("MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf", Alias = "Material")]
```

Set the build action as **'embedded resource'** on the .tff file. Do not forget this step!

[image]

Go this page https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/font/MaterialIcons-Regular.codepoints - to view all of the material **codepoints.**

[image]

In this case I will use the 'alarm-add' icon as an example (because why not). If you want to use the 'alarm-add' icon - find the 'alarm-add' codepoint. In this case the code for the 'alarm-add' icon's **codepoint** is `e856`.

[image]

Paste the following code into your shell:

```
      <ShellContent Title="About"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}"
                      >
            <ShellContent.Icon>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="Material"
                                 Color="White"
                                 Glyph="&#xe856;">
                </FontImageSource>
            </ShellContent.Icon>
            
            
        </ShellContent>
```

If you follow all of the steps - the result should be like so:

[image]

If - by any chance - you want to use material icons **outside of your shell** you can create a Label which has the font family set as `Material` and as the `Text` property you can set the appropriate codepoint. Remember to include `&#x` before the codepoint - and always end it with a semicolon.

*You can customise the colours and icon to whatever you like - just search the **codepoint document** for the icon you want and paste the codepoint which identifies that particular icon.*

Comment: That is certainly an excellent _alternative_  but my goal is to understand what I'm overlooking - there is a gap in my understanding that is not filled by a different implementation.

Comment: @ScottBaker please have a read of https://dev.to/peedroca/material-font-icons-on-xamarin-forms-2a9h if you want to use material fonts. I don't think you are doing it entirely right - take the easiest route if there is no alternative.

Comment: @ScottBaker please review my updated answer.

Comment: This is _yet another_ different implementation.  I get what you're saying, but this implementation should work... and I want to know why it doesn't, not how to work around it.