# TabbedPage tab icons not working with font awesome

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I'm trying to add icons to my tabs with font awesome, in my Xamarin iOS/android app, I looked in many tutorials and I tried to do the same but something is wrong with the following code:

```
<TabbedPage.Children>

       <mypages:List Title="Lista">
           <Tab.Icon>
               <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Glyph="&#xf2bb;" Size="Small" />
           </Tab.Icon>
       </mypages:List>

</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Everything worked until I add the `<Tab.Icon>` Stuff.

Comment: Could you precise what is not working exactly?

Comment: Well, when I compile the code I receive an error saying: "The attachable property "Icon" was not found in type 'Tab' ", with <Tab.Icon> underlined.

Comment: But the icons work in labels and stuffs

Comment: TabbedPage is working fine, the only part that is not working is the icon part

Comment: Did you eventually solve this? I'm currently running into the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

The error you got is self-explanatory:

> "The attachable property "Icon" was not found in type 'Tab' ", with <Tab.Icon> underlined.

There is no property called `Icon` in type `Tab`, you can use below but as you can see, it is `IconImageSource` which requires to provide a resource image name and not a font glyph.

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
        <apptest:Page2 IconImageSource="imageName.png"/>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

An alternative in order to use font icons would be to use [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) to build your tabs instead of `TabbedPage`, which provides font icon support thru `FontImageSource`:

```
<Shell>
...
<Tab Title="title">
   <Tab.Icon>
         <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesome" Glyph="{x:Static fonts:IconFont.AddressBook}"/>
   </Tab.Icon>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"/>
</Tab>
```

Details about fontawesome in xamarin.forms: [How to use Font Awesome icons in project as an icon of ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65095134)

Comment: And how do I connect an existing XAML to that tab? the same way?

Comment: As you probably in Shell docs it is a different syntax/hierarchy, o you will probably need to spend some time (more or less depending on your app size) to migrate toward Shell. [Shell.Tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs)

Comment: @Cfun Your answer resolved my conflict, thank you