# Binding Fontawesome icons to a dynamic list in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, font-awesome

I have a list of icons that need to be dynamically bound to a Xamarin page.

The Xaml is:

```
<Label
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    Style="{StaticResource IconLabelStyle}"
    Text="{Binding Features}"/>
```

where Features is a  comma separated list of Fontawesome icons.  Hardcoded hex values work

```
&#xf236;  &#xf1eb;
```

Unicode values just render as

```
"\uf236  \uf1eb"
```

How can I get the list of icons to render as a complete list?

Ok this is really strange.

**This works**

```
 string features = "\uf236  \uf1eb \uf540  \uf2e7  \uf2cc \uf084 \uf26c \uf001 \ue065 \uf206";
FeaturesList = features;
```

**This doesnt**

```
FeaturesList = model.Features;
```

Where Features list is the bound list on the page. Model.features contains exactly the same values as the string features.  Thanks for all the help

Comment: what exactly is contained in `Features`?  Please give a specific example

Comment: string value "\uf0c2"

Answer (score 2):

Based on your statement

> where Features is a comma separated list of Fontawesome icons. Hardcoded hex values work

I will assume the below code interpretation of `Features`, you will need to:

- Split each icon's code and remove extra spaces.
- Assign divided icon's codes to a `List<string>` property, in order to bind to the UI.

```cs
string Features = "\uf236, \uf1eb, \uf540, \uf2e7, \uf2cc, \uf084, \uf26c, \uf001, \ue065, \uf206";
public List<string> IconsList { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        IconsList = Features.Trim().Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In your UI you can use bind `IconsList` property using `BindableLayout`, `CollectionView` or `ListView`:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding IconsList}" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label FontFamily="FontAwesome" Text="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

**Note**

If you are adding/removing (not only during first appearing of the page), then you may need to change the type `List<string>` to `ObservableCollection<string>`.

This answer doesn't cover how to set-up fonteawesome icons for that take a look at [How to use Font Awesome icons in project as an icon of ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65095134/5228202)

#### Docs

- [How to separate strings using String.Split in C#: .Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split)
- [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts)

Comment: you should be able to show multiple font icons in a single label without splitting them into a list

Comment: Yes right but I am not sure what the OP needs exactly is just an assumption maybe he needs to use one single Label or maybe he has other stuff to add before/after each icon!?

Comment: @amun1000 make sure to specify `FontFamily` on your Label, also make sure your embedded font setup is fine, you can take a look at the link i provided

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a single `Label` to implement it .

#### Custom Label

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyTextProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(MyLabel), null, propertyChanged: BindingPropertyChangedDelegate);

    public string MyText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
    }

    static void BindingPropertyChangedDelegate(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (newValue == null) return;

        var IconsList = ((string)newValue).Trim().Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();

        if (IconsList == null || IconsList.Count == 0) return;

        FormattedString text = new FormattedString();

        foreach(var str in IconsList)
        {
            text.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = "  " });
            text.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = str, FontFamily = "FontAwesomeSolid"});
        }

        ((Label)bindable).FormattedText = text;
    }
}
```

#### Xaml Usage

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyForms.View"

<local:MyLabel MyText="{Binding Features}"/>
```

#### Code behind

```
Features = "\uf164,\uf140,\uf236,\uf1eb,\uf5e1,\uf14a,\uf14b,\uf520,\uf14d,\uf14e,\uf578,\uf15c";
this.BindingContext = this;
```

[image]

Refer to

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thanks for  both solutions but neither seemed to work.  Still getting hard coded characters being displayed for the BindableLayout and no text on the custom control  - Label.  Is there a working solution of the above ? - thanks

Comment: Did you follow the link I provided  to display font awesome ?

Comment: Test on a normal Label to see if it displays like [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/wp-content/uploads/sites/44/2020/04/aeZ94Faz.png) ?

Comment: Yep - all followed.  Incidentally when i changed the hex to unicode the icons displayed.  However when i bind them to the model "string FeatureIcons = model.Features;" with unicode values the values have \\ which need stripping off but i cant
Just to be clear the icons displayed using the bindable layout

Comment: Can you show the value of  `model.Features` ?

Comment: `Label.Text`  supports `hex  string` but `Span.Text` only supports `unicode string`  according to my test .

Comment: \uf236  \uf1eb \uf540  \uf2e7  \uf2cc, \uf084, \uf26c, \uf001, \ue065, \uf206

Comment: You need to add , to separate every single Unicode icon , so that it can divide that into a working list .

Comment: Posted an update to initial question

Comment: Can you provide a basic, reproducible project ? Since I can't be able to reproduce it

Comment: Hi , did you solve the probelm ?