# How to use a Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Path for the ToolbarItem's IconImageSource?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `Settings.xaml` file:

```
<Path xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:drawables="clr-namespace:App.Resources.Drawables"
  x:DataType="drawables:Settings"
  x:Class="App.Resources.Drawables.Settings"
  Data="M12,15.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 8.5,12A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 12,8.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 15.5,12A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 12,15.5M19.43,12.97C19.47,12.65 19.5,12.33 19.5,12C19.5,11.67 19.47,11.34 19.43,11L21.54,9.37C21.73,9.22 21.78,8.95 21.66,8.73L19.66,5.27C19.54,5.05 19.27,4.96 19.05,5.05L16.56,6.05C16.04,5.66 15.5,5.32 14.87,5.07L14.5,2.42C14.46,2.18 14.25,2 14,2H10C9.75,2 9.54,2.18 9.5,2.42L9.13,5.07C8.5,5.32 7.96,5.66 7.44,6.05L4.95,5.05C4.73,4.96 4.46,5.05 4.34,5.27L2.34,8.73C2.21,8.95 2.27,9.22 2.46,9.37L4.57,11C4.53,11.34 4.5,11.67 4.5,12C4.5,12.33 4.53,12.65 4.57,12.97L2.46,14.63C2.27,14.78 2.21,15.05 2.34,15.27L4.34,18.73C4.46,18.95 4.73,19.03 4.95,18.95L7.44,17.94C7.96,18.34 8.5,18.68 9.13,18.93L9.5,21.58C9.54,21.82 9.75,22 10,22H14C14.25,22 14.46,21.82 14.5,21.58L14.87,18.93C15.5,18.67 16.04,18.34 16.56,17.94L19.05,18.95C19.27,19.03 19.54,18.95 19.66,18.73L21.66,15.27C21.78,15.05 21.73,14.78 21.54,14.63L19.43,12.97Z"
  Fill="White"
  x:Key="SettingsIcon" />
```

And the `Settings.xaml.cs` file is simply:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Settings : Path
{
    public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I presume I'm using `IconImageSource` incorrectly as the icon just fails to show and I can't seem to find any documentation on how to properly use it with a `Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Path`.
As a test, I have tried using it like so:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:App="clr-namespace:App.Views.Shared"
       x:DataType="App:Layout"
       Title="App"
       x:Class="App.Views.Shared.Layout"
       FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ContentPage Title="App">
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="Resources\Drawables\Settings.xaml" />
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <AbsoluteLayout>
                <Frame HasShadow="True" WidthRequest="64" HeightRequest="64" CornerRadius="4" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</Shell>
```

Is it at all possible to use a `Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Path` (effectively an SVG, I believe) as a `ToolbarItem.IconImageSource` value?

Comment: IconImageSource does not support svg

Comment: @Cfun Okay, thanks. I would appreciate if you could offer alternative approaches, if possible :)

Comment: possibly you can convert your svg to a png during runtime

Comment: @Cfun I may be able to get away with using font icons instead (which apparently under the hood does what you suggest anyway). Thank you :)

Comment: i just noticed that the svg is a setting icon, it is easier to use icons then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to use font icons like font aweosme.

Details and steps on ow to set it up: [How to use Font Awesome icons in project as an icon of ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65095134/5228202)

At the end use it in your `ToolbarItem` like:

```
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem>
            <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
                <FontImageSource Glyph="{x:Static fonts:IconFont.Cog}"
                                 FontFamily="FontAwesome"/>
            </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up doing, cheers :)