# How to use custom font (external font) in WebView as Embedded Resource in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

Xamarin Forms 4.5 introduced a new way to add **Custom font** (External font) as an **Embedded Resource** in our project, so that Font file needs to be added only in the shared project and not in every project such as Android iOS and UWP. Please note that I am using this approach.

Now coming to the question, I want to use Custom Font as an Embedded Resource in a `WebView` in Xamarin Forms. How to do it. I have done all the prerequisites for it, like Set Build Action - EmbeddedResource, added ExportFont Code [as specified here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61276815/8304176). Also please note that I can use Custom font on a `Label` and `Button` in my Page. I just want to use the same Embedded Font in a `WebView`.

**Here is my XAML code:**

```xml
<WebView x:Name="SampleWebView" HeightRequest="400" />
```

**The Code Behind C#:**

```cs
private void RenderTextOnWebView()
{
    HtmlWebViewSource htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
    htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
                        <head>
                            <style>
                                @font-face {
                                    font-family: myFirstFont;
                                    src: url(MyApplication/Fonts/MonotypeCorsiva.ttf);
                                }

                                div {
                                    font-family: myFirstFont;
                                }
                            </style>
                        </head>

                        <body>
                            <h1>The font Example</h1>
                            <div>With CSS, websites can finally use fonts other than the pre selected web - safe fonts.</div>                
                        </body>
                        </html>";

    SampleWebView.Source = htmlSource;
}
```

Comment: The url does not work if you put the custom font file in shared project. It works fine if you put them in iOS/Android project. Will do more research and update you if I find anything.

Comment: @AmirHajiha, I wanted to show rich text, and this was my workaround to show rich text using `WebView` which was not recommended. Hence, I switched my approach. I used `Span` property of the `Label` to show rich text having multiple formatted text inside a label. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62123258/8304176, It depends on what you want to achieve, If you would tell me, I would suggest you a solution.

Comment: @JunaidPathan my requirement is to have one copy of the font file only in the shared project (Embedded Fonts) and be able to reference it in style.css which is used for the webview.

Comment: @AmirHajiha, No, I mean, why do you need a `WebView`? What are you displaying on it, can it be done using `Label` with `Span` as it was in my case? Generally, we don't need a `WebView` with supporting a custom font, as `WebView` is mostly used to display web content that is already on the web with all the markup we need. Think of it at a basic level, why are you using a `WebView`?

Comment: My app has a feature: in-app HTML display (but I need to ensure the displayed font is my own font and not what's already in the HTML page).

Comment: Please be specific while asking for help, specify what you have tried, what you think could work. Not technically, but in basic terms. Let's assume you can't use Embedded font in `WebView`, now how will you have a workaround to fix it? You can ask a new question about what and how you want your content to be displayed, mention your content, what and how you want it to be displayed. Tag me here linking that question.

Comment: @AmirHajiha, I don't think you can use Embedded Font in a `WebView` so far. In your scenario, your approach might be wrong. Mostly we don't need a `WebView` to display in-app content. You can achieve that using `Label`'s `Span` property to display contents in Embedded font. Using a `WebView` with customization might make your UI heavy resulting in lags. However, you can host content on a server with required font and show it in your `WebView`.

Comment: @AmirHajiha, but that too isn't recommended. In mobile development, always use native controls to show contents, only get text or other data through APIs to be shown inside your native controls. Like text/string inside `Label` and images/photos inside `Image`. Only the data should be fetched from the web.