# How to add Rich Text or HTML in Label or Text field in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add **Rich Text** or **Formatted Text** in `Label` or any Text Field in my Xamarin Forms project. I have tried using separate Labels for the text and also using `WebView`, etc. But none of them worked. Using a `Webview` worked somehow, but it needed to refresh every time the contents were changed. Using AJAX with `WebView` would require a Web Server hence it cannot work locally/offline.

I just want to add Rich text on `Label` in Read only mode, or can be modified from the code behind at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are basically 2 ways to do it.

**1]** You can use `Span` property of a `Label` to enter formatted text inside `Label` Just like:

```xml
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="This is a " FontSize="15" TextColor="Blue"/>
            <Span Text="Rich Text" FontSize="30" TextColor="Red"/>
            <Span Text=" inside a Label in Xamarin Forms" FontSize="15" TextColor="Blue" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

You can also use `Binding` in `Span` and every style and other properties of `Label` inside `Span`.

---

**2]** The second method is, use `TextType` property of `Label` and set it to `TextType="Html"`. But please note that `Label TextType="Html"` has limited supported HTML tags according to the underlying platform on which the app runs.

We can define HTML in the C# code behind or directly in XAML.

**Inside C# code behind:**

```cs
Label richTextLabel = new Label
{
    Text = "This is <strong style=\"color:red\">HTML</strong> text.",
    TextType = TextType.Html
};

// OR 
richTextLabel.Text = "This is <strong style=\"color:red\">HTML</strong> text."
richTextLabel.TextType = TextType.Html;
// In XAML set Label Name as <Label x:Name="richTextLabel" />
```

**In XAML**

```
<Label Text="This is &lt;strong style=&quot;color:red&quot;&gt;HTML&lt;/strong&gt; text."
       TextType="Html"  />

<!--The symbols <, >, " needs to be escaped -->
```

---

> [RE: Refer this for more documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label)

**Conclusion:**
The First method using `Span` is much reliable as everything will be rendered as coded.
In the second method, most of the HTML markup is not supported by `Label` in different underlying platforms.
Hence the first method is recommended.